# Deleting a directory

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to remove an entire directory but I am having issues.

**The Issue**

When trying to delete a directory, it is just not working. I know Stackoverflow HATES that answer, but it is the truth, no error. In fact, it gives me the 'successful' message.

Here is when it gets tricky. If I make a folder in the directory and add a few dummy files, it will work, but if I use it with folders that are already there, it will not remove it.

```
 Dim loc As String = "\\drtnas01\storeprofiles"   'Profile Location
    Dim dfile As String = "\" & BatchTextBox.Text
    Dim path As String = loc & dfile

    VDIRebuildBG.ReportProgress(10, "Looking for Profile")
    BatchStatusBox.Style = ButterscotchAlertBox.AlertStyle.Success
    If Directory.Exists(path) Then
        VDIRebuildBG.ReportProgress(20, "Profile Found")
        BatchStatusBox.Style = ButterscotchAlertBox.AlertStyle.Success
        Try
            VDIRebuildBG.ReportProgress(30, "Starting Rebuild")
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, True)
        Catch
            VDIRebuildBG.ReportProgress(100, "Error Rebuilding")
            BatchStatusBox.Style = ButterscotchAlertBox.AlertStyle.Error
        End Try
        VDIRebuildBG.ReportProgress(100, "Profile Rebuilt")
        BatchStatusBox.Style = ButterscotchAlertBox.AlertStyle.Success

    Else
        VDIRebuildBG.ReportProgress(100, "Profile Not Found")
        BatchStatusBox.Style = ButterscotchAlertBox.AlertStyle.Error
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Note, I have permissions, as I am able to delete the folder manually.

Note 2: The folder is located on a server (so it is kinda slow) and the size of the folder(s) are 50-100mb, not sure if it is timing out or something?

**Edit:** For the hell of it, I copied a folder, and put it into my test folder, then tried it, and it did not delete. This leads me to beleave it is something size related.

**Edit II (3/16):** I did some more testing, and wanted to relay the information I have discovered. Running the code to delete, will delete ALL files in the folder(s), but will NOT remove the file structure. If I run the code again, it will not delete any of the remaining folders. I also tried hardcodeing a folder path that was deep in the subfolders to delete (note, the folder was empty), and that also would not delete the folder.

I also tested permissions issues by having a folder (with several subfolders) on my desktop, where I would have full access. Doing that resulted in the same issue.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger?  *You* may have permission, but is the program running under your account?  Is this a WinForms, ASP.NET?  What is `VDIRebuildBG`?   There appears to be some context lacking in your question.

Comment: @ Tim VDIRebuildBG is a background worker. The entire form is a WinForm. - Also, going to do the Step Through now.

Comment: Exactly - when the program runs, it may not have perms.  Try running the program as Administer and it might work.

Comment: @thehappymamba just tried it, same results. I did notice something. It removes all the files, just dont remove the directory, and all sub directory's

Comment: Have the perms on the existing folders been modified to allow deletion?  For example, the code checks if the directory exists, but not if it is accessible for removal (Access Control List):  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0dw80ts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.  One thing you can try is seeing if it lets you move the directory elsewhere and then delete the new directory.  I recall having to do something dumb like that before with windows.  If windows had something equivalent to /dev/null, you could just move the directory there and be done with it.  Edit it does!  Try moving it to NUL.

Comment: @dwb - are the directories empty when you try to delete them?  i.e., have all files and sub directories been deleted before you attempt to delete the directory?

Comment: @thehappymamba so you are suggesting moving the entire folder to path of 'nul'? I will starting trying that, stand by! EDIT: I tried the simple Directory.Move(path, NUL) not sure if when you said 'NUL' you meant something more or less then the exact term.

Comment: @tim they are not empty.

Comment: @dwb - I'm not 100% sure, but I think the folder has to be empty to delete it.  At least it does when you're working in DOS.

Comment: @tim I got a temp-fix in place, just running a cmd prompt for it, but I hate cmd, as its hard to have error catchers in it.

Comment: Maybe they're some hidden or system files. Did you check those? You should iterate on them and change their attrs to Normal. In others words: Is the top directory REALLY empty?

Comment: A little something to keep in mind is that just because you have permission, it doesn't mean that your app have. Have you tried running it as administrator?

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes, I have tried that with the same results.

Comment: Well, I walked through your code, tested it on local and network folders (with subfolders & files) and it worked perfectly with all these cases. **But** I just noticed something weird.. it won't delete any folder that has (*or had*) a custom icon even if the default icon is restored! maybe this could help.. but I have to mention that -in this case- it throws an `Access is denied` exception, while you said that you're not getting any errors!

Comment: @GeniuSBraiN I get no errors when I run it, it just jumps to the "Rebuilt" section. As for the strange folder issue, any ideas on how to get rid of those pesky folders? (Note, I don't think any of the folders have/had custom icons)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, looks like [Directory.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62t64db3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method has some issues (like not deleting a folder with custom icon as I mentioned in the comment above).

I suggest you use [FileSystem.DeleteDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.deletedirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) instead..

So, try to replace this line:

```
System.IO.Directory.Delete(path, True)
```

with:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(path, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.DeletePermanently)
```

Or *in case you don't want to permanently delete the directory (local folders only)*:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(path, FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
```

I've tried that and it solved my problem.. probably it will solve yours as well.

**Reference:** [How to: Delete a Directory in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24t911bf(v=vs.100).aspx)

I hope this helps :)

Comment: You sir, are a saint. Worked like a charm. Thanks so much for the quick reply, sorry I could not offer more to my bounty! EDIT: I cannot award bounty for 24 hours, so I will do it tomorrow.

Comment: It's okay.. glad I've helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a coworker run into the problem of `Directory.Delete` not working correctly. So I was curious what the differences were based on Ahmed Abdelhameed's post.

If you decompile the Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, you will find that `My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory` ultimately calls `System.IO.Directory.Delete` if you show no UI, otherwise if you show a UI it calls shell32.dll.

So if you call `DeleteDirectory(path, DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)`, then it ultimately calls `Directory.Delete(fullPath, true)`.

Now you might notice that from `DeleteDirectory(path)` to `Directory.Delete(fullPath)` the variable name changed. This is because the `DeleteDirectory(path)`, does this: `String fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path)` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,1274738792cce835), and then passes in the fullPath value instead.

Now if you have a look at the System.IO.Directory.Delete code (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/directory.cs,7edbf8078ebb7f63), you will see that when you call `Delete(path, recursive)`, it does something similar in that it calls `System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(path)` (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,72f9fabbc9d544a5) and uses that to then call an internal/private function called `Delete(fullPath, userPath, recursive, checkHost)`.

The public `GetFullPath` first calls the `GetFullPathInternal(path)`, but it also calls (for non-Core) `FileIOPermission.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess.PathDiscovery, fullPath, false, false)`. `GetFullPathInternal` does not call the `QuickDemand` method.

So the public Directory.Delete method bypasses the `QuickDemand` check by calling `GetFullPathInternal` directly. This might be because the internal `Directory.Delete` method ultimately calls `FileIOPermssion.QuickDemand(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, demandPath, false, false)`, so maybe they're assuming they don't need to call the PathDiscovery permission because they are calling the Write permission.

This would be my guess as to why Directory.Delete is sometimes throwing a Access is denied exception when the VB `FileSystem.DeleteDirectory` does not. If someone runs across the right circumstances to cause this failure in the future, I would be curious if calling `Directory.Delete(Path.GetFullPath(path), true))` fixes the issue or not.